# getlogin_r and getutxent equivalent in mingw for windows

Tags: windows, terminal, mingw

I am porting my old code from *ix to Windows (on mingw).
A part of the old code contains functionality which gets information about users who logged in from the terminal - using **getlogin_r and getutxent** functions provided at *ix.

I am not able to find equivalent in MINGW.
Can somebody please help me to find the equivalent in Mingw for windows programming?

Comment: Looking for the same thing but with VC++.  +1

Comment: Can you use the informations from environment variables?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [gnulib](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/gnulib.html), it supports [MinGW too](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/gnulib.html#Target-Platforms) (but not all modules are available there).

- **`getutxent`**: not available on MinGW
  (*"This function is missing on some platforms: Mac OS X 10.3, FreeBSD 6.0, OpenBSD 3.8, Minix 3.1.8, mingw, MSVC 9, BeOS."*)
- **`getlogin_r`**: available on MinGW
  ("*Portability problems fixed by Gnulib: This function is missing on some platforms: NetBSD 3.0, Minix 3.1.8, mingw, MSVC 9.*")

As an alternative you can *emulate* them with Win API.

- [How to get the username in MinGW?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13612199/how-to-get-the-username-in-mingw/14696909#14696909)
- [LoadUserProfile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762281%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) *function* / [PROFILEINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773378%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) *structure*
- [NetUserGetLocalGroups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370655%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) *function*
- [Windows Shell documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773177%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)