# How to get the username in MinGW?

Tags: c, mingw

To get the user name from Windows, using MinGW, should I use the function getlogin() from unistd.h, or the Windows function GetUserName?

Thank you.

Comment: `getlogin()` is not available in mingw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the `USERNAME` variable:

```
char *name = getenv("USERNAME"); // Get environmentvariable for Username

if( name == NULL )
    return -1; // Username not found ...
else
    printf("%s\n", name); // Output Username
```

If you are fully on Windows you can use its API (`GetUserName()`) too:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <Lmcons.h>

// ...

TCHAR name [ UNLEN + 1 ];
DWORD size = UNLEN + 1;

if( GetUserName((TCHAR*) name, &size) )
    printf("%s\n", name); // Output Username
else
    return -1; // Username not found ...
```

### In general:

- use **`getlogin()`** if you are on **linux / unix** since it's *not* available in MinGW
- use **`GetUserName()`** if you are on **windows**
- use **both** (conditional group preprocessor) with you want to stay **platform independend**

Comment: Just let me notice that the first way (getenv("USERNAME")) is not safe.

Comment: Thats true, but for eg. simple programs ("hello user xy") its enough. If your live depends on it, better use the api functions :-) . Btw. if you are on unix / linux the variable is `LOGNAME`, `USERNAME` is Win only. Anyway you should always check the return value or error code to be shure its working.

Answer (score -1):

The above answer did not work for me.

```
char *name = getenv("USERNAME");
```

giving error

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Instead I used

```
username=$(whoami)
```

and with

```
echo $username
```

I got my windows user name